# Autohotkey v2 version hotstring call function problem

Tags: autohotkey

I have been studying AHK recently, but I have encountered problems recently
Very simple question.Why the second one doesn't work

```
addCodeBlock(code){
    MsgBox code
}
text(){
    Send "11111"
}

:X:``j::text()
:X:``p::addCodeBlock("python")
::asd::asdadda
```

It is only related to the sequence. Only the first one is executed. I can't figure out why this happens, just like the call in X mode is locked
As long as I change the position of the key two lines, only the first line is always valid, but I can use the third line in it,

fuction text run

```
:X:``j::text()
:X:``p::addCodeBlock("python")
```

fuction addCodeBlock run

```
:X:``p::addCodeBlock("python")
:X:``j::text()
```

I want to call different functions through hotstring to achieve their respective functions. If I don't use hotstring, what method is better
help me,3Q

Answer (score 0):

This is a v2 bug

https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/v2.0.2/source/script.cpp#L1829
https://github.com/AutoHotkey/AutoHotkey/blob/v2.0.2/source/script.cpp#L2293
The escape is handled here in the source code, but the buf_length is not updated.

from https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=114290